# How to model this relationship in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR, and I'm creating an application that will have three entities that are related as follows:

```
Foo (1)     :   FooBar (1..N)
FooBar (1)  :   FooBarBar (0..M)
```

I know how to create the model in a database using DDL statements, but its not clear how to model this in the RoR framework (I don't find the documentation very clear)

Comment: `Foo has_many :foo_bars`, `FooBar has_many :foo_bar_bars` is the usual notation. Rails doesn't enforce minimums on `has_many` relationships, so you'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is very clear about nested associations:

> The has_many :through Association A has_many :through association is
>   often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model.
>   This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched
>   with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a
>   third model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients
>   make appointments to see physicians.

[image]

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
  has_many :foo_foo_bars, through: :foo_bars
end

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  has_many :foo_foo_bars
end
```